# How to get a new dataframe with column count out of groupby function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm grouping my data based on `created_at_hour` and count the sum. Which I have no problem doing that. However, I want to get a new dataframe with just those two columns. How can I do that?

Here's the example of my data

```
created_at, user_id
xxx, x
```

And this is what I have done so far.

```
data.created_at = pd.to_datetime(data.created_at)
data['created_at_minute'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['created_at'].minute, axis=1)
data['created_at_day'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['created_at'].day, axis=1)
data['created_at_hour'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['created_at'].hour, axis=1)
group_by = data.groupby(['created_at_hour']).agg(['count'])
group_by.plot()
```

Which I get a graph like this.

[image]

All is good, but now I want to have a new dataframe with just `created_at_hour` and the new `count` column from `groupby` how can I do that? This is the result so far.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `data.groupby(['created_at_hour']).created_at.agg(['count'])` to do the aggregation only on one column (in this case `created_at`).  Then your resulting DataFrame will only have one column.  It will still have a MultiIndex column index because you used `.agg(['count'])` (passing a one-element list).  If you only want to do one aggregation, you can instead use `.agg('count')` or just `.count()`.